# How to solve vector problem

Tags: geometry

The equation of the plane is x-2y-2z=27. It can be written in the form r.n=d(n and r are vector） here where d gives the distance of the origin from the plane, which I worked out to be 9 (can someone verify?). How do I work out the point which is the reflection of the origin? The answer is (6, -12, -12), but how to work out?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "the reflextion of the origin" .

Comment: Apparently that "reflection of the origin", which I've never heard of, is the product of the standard normal to the plane times $\;6\;$ . Why? Beats me...

Answer (score 2):

The normal vector to the plane is $i - 2j - 2k$. The reflection of the origin on the plane is a point on this vector and hence has coordinates $(k, -2k, -2k)$. The midpoint of this point and the origin is $(k/2, -k, -k)$ and this must lie on the plane. Thus $$k/2 + 2k + 2k = 27$$ and hence $k = 6$. Thus the reflection is $(6, -12, -12)$.